# SmsManager.sendDataMessage(..., onSpecificPort , ...,.. ) Is not Filtering SMS On Port Basis

Tags: android, sms

What i want to do is

Send SMS on a specific PORT and application listening to sms receiving for the same port should only react to the sms receiving.

I have a receiver like this

```
    <receiver android:name=".BinarySMSReceiver"> 
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED"/>
            <data android:port="8091"/>
            <data android:scheme="sms"/> 
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>
```

and sending sms like below

```
manager.sendDataMessage(phonenumber, null, (short) SMS_PORT, data, piSend, piDelivered);
```

MyReceiver did receive the msg but issue along side others receivers are also able to listen.

My native inbox of device is also catching the sms.

If i declare another receiver with different port number they are also able to listen.
verified with my logs.

or if i change port number for my first receiver even then it receives .

Only god know why this port is not filtering sms.

Please gave suggestions.
Any direction or hint or solution are welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think it's possible. The whole point of listeners is that they intercept whatever they're meant to intercept. And you can't modify another application from your application (afaik), let alone the default android broadcastreceiver.

Comment: then for what reason did google developers added this port argument in the method call.?

Comment: on which device  are you testing this app?

Comment: Samsung Galaxy POP android 2.1

Comment: @imrankhan Does this works for you for any of your devices. ?

Comment: @Javanator yes this work only for  hTC or LG devices for samsung device  make your own logic bez i was try many time but data sms always show in inbox on Smansung device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is that this port filtering doesn't work well for all the devices of different manufacturers.

Workaround is

Try sending simple text messages.
With in the message body add some of your own header information 
to let your receiver know that it is your sms.

Like

messageBody = "//someHeaderPattern:" + messageBody;

make your receiver listening priority very high.

If your receiver detect its your sms. abortBroadcast to avoid other listen the same.
else do nothing.

This is just a workaround nothing is guaranteed