# Which destination port to use when sending data message?

Tags: android, port

I am currently developing an android app and i want to send data message with audio file attached to it.  One of the arguments of the sendDataMessage() methods is "destination port".

I know its the port i want to send the message via, but I am not sure what to put there, is there a default port for sending data messages?  I have looked for it but every example I have seen uses different port. However, whichever port I use, I get Null PDU exception.

I am using HTC for running and testing the app btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default is 8091. Most devices don't support port filtering very well, though:

[SmsManager.sendDataMessage(..., onSpecificPort , ...,.. ) Is not Filtering SMS On Port Basis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616261/smsmanager-senddatamessage-onspecificport-is-not-filtering-sms-o)

Your null PDU is probably not because of a port selection problem, though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Any idea what could cause the null PDU exception?

Comment: Post your code and stacktrace in a separate question please. You have better odds of sorting it out that way...